# WordPress JQuery Button to PHP db function causes 404 error on JQuery url: parameter

Tags: php, jquery, json, wordpress

I have looked at a dozen stackoverflow examples, w3schools, etc of this and tried to emulate the nuances of each but for whatever reason, but I am tripping over something [stupid] that is causing a 404 error on the url: '/public/class-lolak9-controller-public.php'.  The trace message in php add_data function of course never makes it into the error log *when* invoked from the button.  The php add_data function does work when called directly.

Any and all pointers appreciated.

At plugin path /public/js/lolak9-training-public.js

```
jQuery("#add_data_button").click(function () {
        console.log("Add Record button pressed.");
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/public/class-lolak9-controller-public.php',
            data: {
                action: 'add_data'
            },
            success: function (new_record_id) {
                console.dir(new_record_id);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }).fail();
    });
```

At plugin path /public/class-lolak9-controller-public.php which works perfectly if called directly.

```
public function add_data() {
    
        if (isset($_GET)) {
            if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {

                $lolak9_core = new Lolak9_Training_Core($this->plugin_name, $this->version);

                if (!$lolak9_core->get_plugin_activation_state()) {
                    return;
                }
                error_log('Made it to add_data function.'); 

         // Several lines deleted for space.
 
                $new_record_id = $this->wpdb->insert_id;
                
                return $new_record_id;
            
                wp_die(); //Added to get proper output.
            }
            die();
        }
```

At plugin path /include/class-lolak9-training.php, In the include setup file:

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
...
   $plugin_controller = new LoLaK9_Controller_Public   ( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
               
   $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_call_add_data_button',         $plugin_controller, 'add_data');
   $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_call_add_data_button',  $plugin_controller, 'add_data');
}
```

I know there are other similar StackOverflow examples, but what comma, single / double quote, prin / bracket, comma / semicolon, whatever am I missing?  A respectful thanks in advance.

Expected result: The add function to run when I pressed the add button.

Comment: Trying to directly target any PHP script file is wrong to begin with, your request needs to go to the AJAX request endpoint. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#url

Comment: Thanks @CBroe.  My bad.  I was unaware that WordPress had special implications for JQuery.  I need to read this entire section.  Thank you again for getting me started in the right direction.